# Installing Ubuntu on SSD

Tags: system-installation, ssd

My HDD died on my laptop and I thought this would be a great time to ditch Windows and try Ubuntu.

What size would you suggest for a SSD?
I don't plan to do much with it besides surfing and building a text MUD locally.

Comment: You can check the requirement for ubuntu here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements
As you can see ubuntu doesn't need a very big HDD its all your choice

Comment: Any Linux supported SSD from 32GB to 2TB would work fine I suppose.

Comment: Prices are down for SSD. I've seen ~1TB SSD for less than ~$130. Buy what you can afford. Bigger is always better.

Comment: @heynnema RAM is coming down too it seems. I'm eyeing a 16GB DDR4 SODIMM for my laptop.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix depending on how many SODIMM slots your laptop has, try to add RAM is equal size pairs for memory interleaving performance.

Comment: @heynnema The interleaving factor is old school. I'll pull out one 4 GB and insert one 16 GB to get 20 GB. They don't have to be paired with identical size and MHz anymore. Android studio is RAM hungry :D

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix interleaving is *old school*? Size/mhz too? Since when? `sudo lshw -c memory`. Prove me wrong.

Comment: @heynnema https://superuser.com/questions/769529/memory-runs-at-flex-memory-mode

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix No no no. That article clearly points out (what I said) that the memory is running in degraded mode (and the BIOS also reports it), and the commentators clearly indicate that another memory module should/could be added to regain full dual channel interleaving. "Flex" memory occurs when unequal RAM pairs are installed, and performance is compromised. I gets more complicated if you've got a quad-channel memory board, where similar spec RAM has to get added in groups of four. Don't mix/match dissimilar spec RAM. (I'm a hardware guy, if you didn't guess).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix ps: in your case, assuming that you've only got two RAM slots, you'd be better off buying either two 8G RAM sticks, or two 16G RAM sticks (if your laptop can handle that much total RAM).

Comment: @heynnema Agreed it would be better. It's $120 for a single 16 GB stick and throwing away one 4 GB stick which serves the purpose today. In a year if need be I'll buy another 16 GB stick. If I buy two 8 GB sticks I'll throw away two 4 GB sticks today. I could possibly throw away two 8 GB sticks in a year if I need two 16 GB sticks. Besides damage to the environment, there is damage to wallet. In two years I'll buy a new laptop and none of the RAM will be up to spec for it.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix how much would two 8G RAM sticks cost for your machine? You could always donate the 4G RAM sticks to one of those places that refurbishes computers for schools and low-income families. No environmental impact then :-) And regarding the wallet... well... you can't take it with you... :-)

Comment: @heynnema Without checking I believe the two 8GB sticks would be about the same as a single 16 GB stick. It will be interesting to do a speed test with current two x 4 GB sticks installed now and then later with 4GB stick + 16 GB stick. Then if performance drop is > 10% I'll simply buy the other 16 GB stick right away.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix first check to make sure that your computer can take 32G RAM.

Comment: @heynnema Very good suggestion. I verified 32 GB was supported before laptop purchase. On Amazon some vendors request your make & model # before RAM purchase and you get "green verified check mark" or "blue not sure hyperlink".

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  You can always check at crucial.com for memory compatibility, and go figure, what they charge for RAM :-)

Answer (score 0):

Even 128GB would work for you. I have a 240GB SSD, still have 120GB space left and I do a lot of gaming. It could be a good idea to get a larger HDD for backups and large files though.

Comment: ehm. I can run Ubuntu on a 20Gb SSD and never run out of space. Just got to keep personal files of the hard disk (like on an USB or always online).

Answer (score 0):

A Linux install like desktop Ubuntu will use about 20GB. The rest of the used space will be for personal files and games.

Comment: Wow, that's small. I'll probably get the 120gb from Newegg for a whole 30 bucks.